# redux-thunk: Pause Component Execution Until Action Creator Completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've been struggling with this problem for several weeks now. I'm finally throwing in the towel and asking for help on this because I'm clearly not doing something right. I have a React.js app that is using redux and redux-thunk. I'm simply trying to get my Component Container to initiate the loading of data, but not render until the data comes back from the fetch request. Seems simple enough I know. Here is what I've done:

**Container Component**

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchActivePlayer } from '../actions/index';
import PlayerDetails from '../components/players/player-detail';
import Spinner from '../components/common/spinner/index';
import store from '../store';

export default class PlayerDetailContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchActivePlayer(this.props.params.player_slug)
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.props.activePlayer.activePlayer) {
            return (
                <Spinner text="Loading..." style="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" />
            );
        }

        return (
            <PlayerDetails 
                player={ this.props.activePlayer.activePlayer } 
            />
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        activePlayer: state.activePlayer
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchActivePlayer })(PlayerDetailContainer);
```

**Action Creator**

```
export function fetchActivePlayer(slug) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/players/${slug}`)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER,
                payload: response
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Failure: ", err);
        });    
    };
}
```

**Store**

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import reducers from './components/reducers/index';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    thunk,
    promise,
    routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
) (createStore);
export default createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
```

**Routes**

```
export default (
<Route path="/" component={ App }>
        <IndexRoute component={ HomePage } />
        <Route path="players/:player_slug" component={ PlayerContainer } />
        <Route path="/:player_slug" component={ PlayerContainer } />
    </Route>
);
```

Here are the versions I'm using for everything:
react = 0.14.7
react-redux = 4.4.1
redux-thunk = 0.5.3

When I run this, I don't receive any errors but it's clear that my action creator is firing but my component container continues instead of waiting for the creator to finish. Like I said, I'm sure I must be missing something really simple but I can't seem to figure out what that is.

Thank you in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean your spinner never shows? Or only your spinner shows?

Comment: Can you include your reducer in your question so we may see your state shape?

Comment: Also, to clear up some language here, you never pause component execution. That's like pausing your brain. UIs are just a constant stream like life, you just render different things based on what the current state is.

Comment: Thank you @azium. My spinner does show. I was trying to get my component to pause loading until my data is returned which I now realize is not possible. I obviously mis-understood the react-thunk component example.

Answer (score 7):

1. your action(fetch) in componentWillMount is async ,component will not wait.
2. Usually when you fetch some data , you want to know about statuses of fetching process. like "isfetching" in order to showing loader, success and failure in order to showing error.
3. **You can use these statuses to not load/mount/launch component, Until Action Creator Completes.**

Thus, you should organize your redux parts somthing like that:

**state**

```
activePlayer:{
    data:data,
    isFetching: true/false,
    error:""
    }
```

**action**

```
export const fetchActivePlayer = slug => dispatch =>{
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
    });

    return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/players/${slug}`)
    .then(response => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER_SUCCESS',
            isFetching:false,
            payload: response
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
        });
        console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });

};
```

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {data:null,isFetching: false,error:null};
export const actionPlayer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER_REQUEST':
        case 'FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER_FAILURE':
        return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, error: action.error };

        case 'FETCH_ACTIVE_PLAYER_SUCCESS':
        return { ...state, data: action.payload, isFetching: action.isFetching,
                 error: null };
        default:return state;

    }
};
```

**then your component might look like this** (hardcode)

```
class PlayerDetailContainer extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchActivePlayer(this.props.params.player_slug)
    }
    render() {
        if (this.props.isFetching) {
            return <Spinner text="Loading..." style="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" />

        }else if (this.props.error) {
            return <div>ERROR {this.props.error}</div>
        }else {
            return <PlayerDetails  player={ this.props.data }  />
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
        isFetching: state.activePlayer.isFetching,
        data: state.activePlayer.data,
        error: state.activePlayer.error,
})
```

**I don't know how your app looks like. Target of this example is to illustrate approach.**

Comment: Thank you Utro. I will try this and get back to you.