# Component structure to handle Async Action with Redux-thunk ?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

After a bit of trial and error I finally manage to get my action creator working properly and passing the data I wanted into my redux store. Until now I've been dispatching it "manually" like this `store.dispatch(fetchTest());` but It would be great if could use these data into a component.

So here is my action creator :

```
export const fetchTest = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
  });
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/authors')
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching:false,
            data: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            ype: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
};
```

Here is my reducer :

```
const initialState = {data:null,isFetching: false,error:null};
export const ThunkData = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST':
        case 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE':
        return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, error: action.error };

        case 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {data: action.data, isFetching: action.isFetching,
                 error: null });
        default:return state;

    }
};
```

So far everything is working properly when using `store.dispatch(fetchTest());`.

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064688/redux-thunk-pause-component-execution-until-action-creator-completes) I tried to build the following component :

```
class asyncL extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                      }
                      componentWillMount() {
                      this.props.fetchTest(this.props.thunkData)
                      // got an error here : "fetchTest is not a function"
                      }
                      render() {
                      if (this.props.isFetching) {
                            return console.log("fetching!")
        }else if (this.props.error) {
            return <div>ERROR {this.props.error}</div>
        }else {
            return <p>{ this.props.data }</p> 
        }
    }
}

            const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
                return {
                    isFetching: state.ThunkData.isFetching,
                    data: state.ThunkData.data.data,
                    error: state.ThunkData.error,
                };
            };


            const AsyncList = connect(mapStateToProps)(asyncL);
            export default AsyncList
```

It doesn't work, I have an error on the `componentWillMount()` and probably somewhere else.

Also my data structure is kind of weird. To actually get to the data array I have to do `state.ThunkData.data.data`. The first data object is full of useless stuff like `request`, `headers`, etc...

So how should I write this component so I can at least passed the Async data into a console.log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `mapDispatchToProps` as well.

```
import { fetchTest } from './myFetchActionFileHere';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchTest: bindActionCreators(fetchTest, dispatch)
  };
}

const AsyncList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(asyncL);
export default AsyncList
```

documentation link: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html